# How to append string inside for loop

Tags: swift

I have user array and I want concat values with ','

```
for s in userArray {

}
```

I want the result be A,B,C,D

How could I do this in Swift 3?

Comment: Why use a loop? Use the `joined` function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the array joined(separator:) function

```
let joined = stringArray.joined(separator: ", ")
```

Comment: what if it's not a stringArray? it's userList I want concat user emails

Comment: `let joined = userArray.map { $0.email }.joined(separator: ",")`